# How to only display a category once from SQL table?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table of products with a column (prodCat) which is an ID column number, this relates to another table I have set-up (rangecat) which links to a column (rangeCatID).

My code is as follows:

```
<?php 
     $querycat = "SELECT DISTINCT products.prodCat, rangecat.rangeCatTitle, rangecat.rangeCatSEO FROM products INNER JOIN ranges ON products.prodRangeID = ranges.rangeID INNER JOIN rangecat ON products.prodCat = rangecat.rangeCatID WHERE rangeSEO = '$seoname' AND prodState = 1";
      $resultcat = $conn->query($querycat);

      while($rowcat = $resultcat->fetch_object()){
      if ($page[3] == $rowcat->rangeCatSEO) { $state = ' class="onstate"'; } else { $state = ''; }
      echo '<li ' .$state. '><a href="/product/' . $prodsub .'/'. $rowcat->rangeCatSEO . '">' . $rowcat->rangeCatTitle . '</a></li>';
      }

      $resultcat->free();
?>
```

Please see following screenshot below which show the category returned multiple times:

[image]

Please see below for products table structure:

[image]

Please see below for rangecat table structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your query has related tables, then the "duplicates" come from the fact that there are related rows in the categories table with other rows in the other tables.

If you want to get only unique rows, you must use either `select distinct` or `group by`. I'd go with `select distinct`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT category -- Or the appropriate column name
FROM products 
    INNER JOIN ranges ON products.prodRangeID = ranges.rangeID 
    INNER JOIN rangecat ON products.prodCat = rangecat.rangeCatID 
-- Add where conditions here
```

Once you've got the unique category, you can create a second statement to get the products for each unique category.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked as you said 100% correct.

Comment: This works very well which outputs the category ID and only displays the category once.

The issue I have now now is I am trying to get the (rangeCatTitle) from (rangecat) table, but this returns nothing?

Comment: @Craig: Consider this: You *need* to include the column in the query if you want to read it; if there are more than one value of `rangeCat` for each category, you'll have duplicate rows again. Think carefully how to get the data in the way you want. On the other hand, you don't post your table structure or any data sample, so there's no way to know how is your data organized.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, please see amended question with table structure images.

Comment: I resolved my answer in the end, the answer was to get the columns on DISTINCT, please see my amended code above (SELECT DISTINCT products.prodCat, rangecat.rangeCatTitle, rangecat.rangeCatSEO FROM products...), many thanks for your help towards this.

Comment: @Craig Happy to help. I'm glad you've found the solution yourself.